# USB: understanding the RESUME and SUSPENDED states

Tags: usb

I do not understand the "RESUME" and "SUSPENDED" modes in the USB protocol (USB 2.0).

The USB 2.0 specification states:

> All devices must suspend if bus activity has not been observed for the length of time specified in
>   Chapter 7. Attached devices must be prepared to suspend at any time they are powered, whether they have
>   been assigned a non-default address or are configured. Bus activity may cease due to the host entering a
>   suspend mode of its own.

The length of time specified in Chapter 7 is 3 frames. I don't understand what does mean "no bus activity": does it means no packets at all? does it means no packets sent to this device (and so if the device detects SOF packets then it should not enter SUSPENDED mode?)

> In addition, a USB device shall also enter the Suspended state when the hub port
>   it is attached to is disabled. This is referred to as selective suspend.

How can a hub port be disabled? Is it the hub port itself that decides to do so (under which condition?) or is it the host that sends a command to the hub to do so (what is this command?)?
Is it correct to assume that for the device point of view, suspend and selective suspend are the same because in both cases the device only sees no bus activity?

> A USB device exits suspend mode when there is bus activity. A USB device may also request the host to
>   exit suspend mode or selective suspend by using electrical signaling to indicate remote wakeup.

I do not understand this part. Why would a USB device requests the host to exit suspend mode or selective suspend because this is always the host that initiates transactions?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Bus activity refers to any packet seen by the device.

I don't know all the details about selective suspend, but I believe that the operating system can tell when nothing is trying to use a USB device, and then tell the USB port to suspend the device to save power.

As for why a USB device would request for the host to exit suspend mode: have you ever noticed that you can wake up your computer from sleep by pressing a key on its keyboard or clicking a button on its mouse?

Comment: If I understand correctly:

the mouse do not send any changing data during a certain amount of time => the computer decides to do a selective suspend and closes the port => because the port is closed, the mouse does not see any bus activity and suspends itself.

For the mouse, there is no difference between a selective suspend and a suspend: both happens because of no bus activity? Or is there a command for a selective suspend that the mouse has to handle?

Comment: But if the mouse decides to wake up, how can it do it because it will see no bus activity?

Comment: Yes, the USB device can't tell how many devices are being suspended.  There is no suspend command.  You can search the USB 2.0 specification for details about "remote wakeup" and "resume signaling": that is how the mouse signals that it wants to end suspend mode.  Maybe section 7.1.7.7 is a good place to start.